# How to extract a HTML table from a specific website to external HTML file?

Tags: java, html, parsing

I was asked to write an app that will download only main table (marked as report_table) from the given URL https://www.ote-cr.cz/en/statistics/electricity-imbalances-1 and store it in a separate HTML file.

I have managed to download the table's content, however, I cannot manage to style it properly as I am asked to. Here is my code:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    System.out.println(doc);
    Element tableElement = doc.select("table.table.report_table").first();

    Elements tableHeaderElements = tableElement.select("thead tr th");
    System.out.println("headers");

    for (int i = 0; i < tableHeaderElements.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(tableHeaderElements.get(i).text());
        writer.append(tableHeaderElements.get(i).text());

        if (i != tableHeaderElements.size() - 1) {
            writer.append(',');
        }
    }
    writer.append('\n');
    System.out.println();

    Elements tableRowElements = tableElement.select(":not(thead) tr");

    for (int i = 0; i < tableRowElements.size(); i++) {
        Element row = tableRowElements.get(i);
        System.out.println("row");
        Elements rowItems = row.select("td");
        for (int j = 0; j < rowItems.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(rowItems.get(j).text());
            writer.append(rowItems.get(j).text());

            if (j != rowItems.size() - 1) {
                writer.append(' ');
            }
        }
        writer.append('\n');
    }

    writer.close();
}
```

What shall I add to my code, in order to get a correctly styled table in a separate HTML?

Comment: From the terms of use - "The Users has no right to reproduce, copy or duplicate the content of this website or published information and data for commercial purposes unless they have an explicit approval from the Operator.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extracts the html table (without css) and saves it to a file

```
public class Parser {
    public void parseAndWrite() {

        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(" https://www.ote-cr.cz/en/statistics/electricity-imbalances-1").get();

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("out.html"));
            System.out.println(doc);
            Element tableElement = doc.select("div.bigtable").first();

            writer.write(tableElement.toString());

            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // LOG may be?
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps